# CheckBoxes play list to play mp3

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have little experience and I needed your help. I have this code written, which is almost what I want. The only difference that I can't solve is that instead of showing up the alert box I would like the mp3 files to start playing in order, one after the other. Can you help?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {

  $("#play_button").click(function() {
    var selected_items = $("#playlist  td input:checked");

    if (selected_items.length == 0) {
      alert("Não foi seleccionada nada.");
    } else {

      var song = [];
     
      selected_items.each(function() {
        song.push($(this).data("song"));
       


      })
            alert(song);


'''

<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="playlist">

    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-song="1.mp3" data-cover="cover1.jpg" data-artist="Linkin Park" name="check[]">
    </td>
    <td>
     mesmo musica.mp3
    </td>
    </td>
 
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" data-song="2.mp3" data-cover="cover1.jpg" data-artist="Linkin Park" name="check[]">
    </td>
    <td>
      mesmo musica 2.mp3
    </td>
    </td>



</table>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="selectall" />select all/deselect all
<input type="submit" id="selectall_button" value="Select All" />
<input type="submit" id="play_button" value="Play selected" /
```

Comment: Can you provide your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Audio(audioFile).play()` to play audio:

```js
$(window).load(function() {
      $("#play_button").click(function() {
            var selected_items = $("#playlist  td input:checked");
            if (selected_items.length == 0) {
              alert("Não foi seleccionada nada.");
            } else {
              var song = [];
              selected_items.each(function() {
                song.push($(this).data("song"));
              })
              song.forEach(e => new Audio(e).play());
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help. The only problem is that they play both at the same time. I would like that the second only start only when the first end